# Oil refinery - How many plates are needed for a 10 degrees difference in temperature?

Tags: physical-chemistry

[image]

I am having some trouble going about this question. My first thought is to set up an ASTM separation equation to figure out the difference, but I do not know how to incorporate the reflux ratio which is 0.5.

ASTM: TBP 50% --> 550 (heavy oil)-300(light oil)= 250 degrees

reflux ratio is 0.5. Do I multiply the ratio by number of plates and then take $\frac{\pu{250 ^\circ C}}{\text{reflux}\times \text{number of plates}}$ to get the answer of 10 degrees?

Comment: Could you please edit in what you have done.

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.‎